# Parsing numeric strings ( 'two point three' into digits ( '2.3' )

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to parse numeric strings like 'twenty two' into '22'. I wrote a function that can do that to some extent, but I'm having some issues parsing something like 'two point three` into 2.3 .

How I thought about doing this would be when I find a number and point follows it to look ahead, but currently my function ignores point and adds the two and three to five.

How would you go about converting `two point three` or decimals written in natural language into strings composed of digits?

Here is my function:

```
function parseNumericString( str ){
    var numbers = /\b(?:(one)|(two)|(three)|(four)|(five)|(six)|(seven)|(eight)|(nine)|(ten)|(eleven)|(twelve)|(?:(?:(thir)|(four)|(fif)|(six)|(seven)|(eigh)|(nine))teen)|(?:(?:(twen)|(thir)|(fou?r)|(fif)|(six)|(seven)|(eigh)|(nine))ty)|(hundred)|(thousand)|(?:(?:(mi)|(bi)|(tri)|(quadri)|(quinti)|(sexti)|(septi)|(octi)|(noni)|(deci))llion))\b/gi
    , total = 0
    ,  part = 0
    , match, i, l, power
    ;
    while( match = numbers.exec( str ) ){
        for( i=0, l=match.length; i<l; i++ ){
            if( !match[i] ){ continue; }
                 // 1-19
                 if( i<20 ){
                     part += i;

                     // 20, 30..90
                 }else if( i<28 ){
                      part += 10 + 10 * ( i-19 );
                      // hundred
                  }else if( i===28 ){
                      part *= 100;

                      // thousand-decillion               
                  }else{
                      var power = Math.pow( 1000, i-28 );

                      // e.g. million ... thousand
                     if( total > power ){
                         total += part * power;

                         // e.g. thousand ... million
                     }else{
                         total += part;
                         total *= power;
                     }

                     part = 0;
                 }
            }
        }

    return total+part;
}
```

Comment: If you are always dealing with strings separated by spaces, another option might be to create this function as follows:  1.  Split string into array via white spaces 2.  Iterate through array and replace word string against lookup in a table / object literal ie. replace 'point' with '.' or 'two' with 2, or push to another array  3.  join array back to string, 4. parseInt base 10 to create number

Comment: Split the string at `'point'` and process each part separately.

Comment: @TedHopp I didn't even think of that. So use to splitting by symbols and regexs! Thanks!